# Oil change problems 2013 chevy camaro

Tags: chevrolet, oil-change, camaro

I drained my old oil, put the plug back, refilled with 5 qrts of oil, started the car, checked the dipstick and it shows about an or more over the fill line.  I pulled the oil plug to drain some excess and there is nothing in the pan.  What the heck is going on????

Comment: I once knew a person who did a first oil change. He drained the engine oil, added 4 quarts to the automatic transmission, then checked the engine dipstick. There was nothing on the dipstick. He bought 2 more quarts, added it, then checked: empty. After several additions of oil, he discovered his mistake. Ruined his transmission.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you drained the transmission and added oil to the engine?.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60507)

Comment: It is the answer. He drained the transmission. Added oil to the engine. Too much oil in the engine. Took off the drain plug again on the empty transmission and no oil came out. It's the only explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The fill amount has to be adjusted whether you changed the filter or not.

I alwayd put in a bit less and work up to the line by adding after running the engine and letting it settle.